# I do not know how to check the results. (BaseHTTPRequestHandler)

Tags: python, basehttprequesthandler

```
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

class aaa(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.wfile.write("Hello World")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = HTTPServer(("", 8888), aaa)
    server.serve_forever()
```

It's a practice to create a web server in **Python**.
but,  I do not know how to check the results.

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to achieve. Are you writing a client or a server or both? The code is the sever side. Where do you want to check the result of which operation? Are you missing a client? Your browser could be your test client.for a http request.

Answer (score 0):

Open a web browser and type `http://localhost:8888/` into the address bar. If you see `Hello World`, it worked. Otherwise, it didn't.

Whether or not it worked, you can see the actual results returned like this. Open a command prompt and type:

```
telnet localhost 8888
```

after the connection completes, type:

```
GET / HTTP/1.0
```

and hit enter twice.

Then the response from the web server should appear.

Comment: I did it the way you told me. but, Localhost has sent an invalid response.(ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE) I get an error...

Comment: oh! it's success in internet Explorer! thank you so much!